# RabbitMQ Client EventingBasicConsumer stops receiving messages

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Using the RabbitMQ.Client v. 6.2.2 I am facing the issue that the  *EventingBasicConsumer* sometimes stops receiving messages if a broker from the cluster fails.

Looking into the issue I am logging the recovery attempts and they usually work quite well. But this weekend the worker stopped receiving messages again and I am searching for advice how to find which side is at fault. The RabbitMQ Server oder the Client and what to do about it.

The configuration for the EventingConsumer is pretty much the default with AutomaticRecoveryEnabled=true and heartbeats every 60s + Topology recovery enabled

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        Uri = new Uri(config.ConnectionString),
        AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
        RequestedHeartbeat = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
        
    };
```

The server logs for the time looks like this

```
2022-01-22 06:43:28.436 [info] <0.12831.3> accepting AMQP connection <0.12831.3> (X.X.X.X:59644 -> X.X.X.X:5672)
2022-01-22 06:43:28.460 [info] <0.12831.3> connection <0.12831.3> (X.X.X.X:59644 -> X.X.X.X:5672): user 'user' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'vhost'
2022-01-22 06:44:52.904 [error] <0.1031.0> ** Node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-server-1.rabbitmq-cluster-nodes.ns' not responding **
** Removing (timedout) connection **
2022-01-22 06:44:52.904 [info] <0.529.0> rabbit on node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-server-1.rabbitmq-cluster-nodes.ns' down
2022-01-22 06:44:52.939 [info] <0.529.0> Node rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-server-1.rabbitmq-cluster-nodes.ns is down, deleting its listeners
2022-01-22 06:44:52.942 [info] <0.529.0> node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-server-1.rabbitmq-cluster-nodes.ns' down: net_tick_timeout
2022-01-22 06:46:07.706 [info] <0.529.0> node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-server-1.rabbitmq-cluster-nodes.ns' up
2022-01-22 06:46:22.468 [info] <0.529.0> rabbit on node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-cluster-server-1.rabbitmq-cluster-nodes.ns' up
```

Client Logs

```
2022-01-22 06:42:44.7370409+00:00  RabbitMqClientEventSource - Received request to BeginAutomaticRecovery, but already in Recovering state.
2022-01-22 06:42:49.7397378+00:00  RabbitMqClientEventSource - Performing automatic recovery
2022-01-22 06:42:49.9343050+00:00  RabbitMqClientEventSource - Connection recovery completed

2022-01-22 06:42:50.1977866+00:00  Received message {MessageId} ...
```

The client recovered successfully and received a single single message before stopping completely until the connection is reset.

I was wondering if the server did break the state of the application by `deleting its listeners`. Looking into the management ui I see that the connection & channels are connected but no consumer is listed for the consumers.

I see some bugs for the recovery in the RabbitMQ Client Library but I am not sure whether they will fix this situation here. The client has a working connection but pretty much isn't a consumer anymore and both sides are happy to continue which is kinda bad for the application.

What would be a good approach to stop this from happening? Implementing a custom reconnect/retry/recovery logic seems a) too complicated b) not pragmatic.

Is there a way to check on client side if I am still a consumer if I haven't received messages for 1-2 minutes? And if so restart the application or force a reconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade to version 6.2.4. I fixed a bug that could have caused what you report here.